# HTML CSS move text upwards when the line breaks

Tags: html, css

I have this li that repeats dynamically, being aligned in 3 columns and various rows.

```
<li class="produto-ind">

            <h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
            </h2>

            <div class="img-produto-ind">
                <div class="fk-img"></div>
            </div>

</li>
```

The text in the h3 is not always the same and that is the problem.

Check this out:

http://jsfiddle.net/2vpMP/1/

As you can see, the first li have more text than the other ones. As the lines of the text break, it forces the div.fk-img to go down, messing up the alignment.

My question is:
Is it possible to make the text move upwards if there is line breaks?

Comment: You could specify a fixed height, so they are all the same regardless of contents. But, I don't think you'll like that answer. http://jsfiddle.net/2vpMP/4/

Comment: You would have to use javascript to do that, is that okay with you?

Comment: do this  `<h2>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet<br/><br/><br/>
            </h2>`

Comment: @watson i am used to javascript, feel free to share.

Comment: @SetSailMedia The problem width your answers is that i want the text to keep close to the div.fk-img

Comment: @Arpit The same to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using inline blocks

You might try this:

```
.produto-ind {
    xxposition: relative;
    width:300px;
    height:400px;
    xxfloat: left;
    margin:50px 30px 0px 0px;
    border: 1px dotted blue;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Instead of using floats, use `display: inline-block`.  The text blocks will align with their bottom baselines.

There are other minor issues related to the height of the div's but those can be fixed, especially if you know the height for `.fk-img`.

See demo at http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/2vpMP/12/

### Using floats

You can also use floats if you know the height of your image container:

```
.produto-ind .img-produto-ind {
    height:290px;
    width:100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
.produto-ind h2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 290px;
}
.produto-ind .fk-img {
    height:100%;
    width:auto;
    background-color:gray;
}
```

In this case, if you know that `.fk-img` will be 290px height, you can use absolute positioning to place the image container at the bottom of the parent `.produto-img` block
and then position the `h2` element 290px off the bottom.

See: http://jsfiddle.net/audetwebdesign/KpCzK/

The choice between inline-blocks and floats depends a lot on how you want the `li` blocks to line up, ragged space on top or ragged space on the bottom, and that is a design decision on you part.

A solution with `display: table-cell` is possible if you wrap your content around a block level element width `display: table-cell; vertical-align: bottom;` but that will also assume that all the image blocks have the same height.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Format:-

```
    <div style="display: table;">
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell; width:300px;">csdcs<br /><br /></div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;width:300px;">Row 1, Cell 1</div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;width:300px;">Row 1, Cell 1</div>
        </div>
        <div style="display: table-row;">
            <div style="display: table-cell;width:300px;">Row 2, Cell 1</div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;width:300px;">Row 2, Cell 1</div>
            <div style="display: table-cell;width:300px;">Row 2, Cell 1</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

It will work..

in this case you can generate `<span>` tag instead of `<li>` and there is no need to create any extra CSS apart from

```
<style>
    #main_div{display: table;}
    #sec_div{display: table-row;}
    #span_generate{ table-cell; width:300px;/*whatever width you wanna give*/}
</style>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aasthatuteja/cCEFs/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
h2 {height:80px; display:table-cell; vertical-align:bottom;}
```